# Create a numerical column in r using factor column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an existing data set in R where I'm looking to build a new numerical column using an existing column. It has the factors "Far", "Near", "On" and I'm trying to use 'mutate' within 'dplyr' (or similar) to create a new column that has corresponding numbers (Far = 3, Near = 2, On = 1). Sorry for no code, I'm new on this forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the levels of the factor column

```r
> # Initial data
> val
[1] Far  Near On   Far  Near
Levels: Far Near On

> # Check the levels
> levels(val)
[1] "Far"  "Near" "On"  

> # Set levels to required values
> levels(val) <- c(3, 2, 1)

> # Result
> val
[1] 3 2 1 3 2
Levels: 3 2 1
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked and it's great. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you find answers helpful, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) them and up-voting.

Comment: Thanks! I just accepted the answer. Unfortunately I cannot upvote it as it seems my account is too new.

Comment: But this does not create a "numerical" column as stated in the actual question. It simply modifies the levels of the factor column, the resulting object remaing as as "factor" with numeric _levels_. If this is what you wanted then modify the question. Otherwise, this does not answer the question.

Comment: Be careful with this solution if you want mathematical operations performed on this new `val` column, which is not numeric. Try doing `val + 1`. You'll get NA NA NA.

Answer (score 2):

First an example data set.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- factor(sample(c("Far", "Near", "On"), 10, TRUE))
```

First, recode the factor with its levels in the required order.

```
codes <- c("Far" = 3, "Near" = 2, "On" = 1)
x <- factor(as.character(x), levels = names(sort(codes)))
```

Now, since factors are coded internally as consecutive integers, a simple coercion is enough.

```
as.integer(x)
#[1] 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1 2
```

Another option is

```
attributes(x) <- NULL
x
#[1] 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1 2
```

Comment: This does not control which numbers are assigned to which factors. As written it codes 'Far' as '1' and 'On' as '3'.

Comment: @BrianStamper You are right, I didn't notice the order in the question. Corrected now, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` function `case_when` would work, within a `mutate`:

```
your_data <- your_data %>%
  mutate(num = case_when(your_factor == "Far" ~ 3,
                         your_factor == "Near" ~ 2,                             
                         your_factor == "On" ~ 1))
```

EDIT, to demo that this does work:

```
> your_data <- data.frame(your_factor = sample(c("Far", "Near", "On"), 10, TRUE))
> glimpse(your_data)
Observations: 10
Variables: 1
$ your_factor <fct> On, Far, Near, Far, Near, Near, On, On, On, On
> your_data <- your_data %>%
  +   mutate(num = case_when(your_factor == "Far" ~ 3,
  +                          your_factor == "Near" ~ 2,                             
  +                          your_factor == "On" ~ 1))
> glimpse(your_data)
Observations: 10
Variables: 2
$ your_factor <fct> On, Far, Near, Far, Near, Near, On, On, On, On
$ num         <dbl> 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1
>
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting - unfortunately I have tried this a few different ways and it simply created a new column with 'NA's present. I did solve the issue but thank you anyway!

Comment: I tried testing this with some data and it worked. Without showing what you have tried it is hard to tell why it didn't for you.

Comment: Apologies - it is difficult to explain what is going on with my data. I was able to solve this issue fortunately but if you'd like I can break down what I tried and what errors I got. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to `unclass` the factor and subtract the result from 4 since factor levels begin at 1L.

```
x <- factor(c("Far","Near","On"))
4 - c(unclass(x))
# [1] 3 2 1
```

Or to keep the levels attribute, omit the `c`.

```
4 - unclass(x) -> y
class(y)
# [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much but unfortunately this did not work. I was able to find the answer though, so thank you for answering my question!

Comment: What do you mean "Did not work"? Your question probably needs more clarification.

Comment: Hi Edward - unfortunately I think it is just my own stupidity. I'm not really sure how to apply this to my data - however I was able to find the answer to my problem.